# Loop through pandas df and find instances in which the previous record are the same as the current one

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe similar to this one:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                 'flag':['duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'duplicate', 'duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'non-duplicate'],
                 'domain':[['cnn.com', 'usatoday.com'], ['nytimes.com', 'reddit.com'], ['cnn.com'], ['cnn.com'], ['nytimes.com', 'reddit.com'], ['washingtonpost.com', 'nytimes.com'], 'cnn.com', 'cnn.com' ],
                 })
```

I'd like to loop through the dataframe and find instances in which the domains are exactly the same as the previous record in the domain series only when the IDs are the same. The end result that I'm hoping for should look similar to this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                 'flag':['duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'duplicate', 'duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'non-duplicate'],
                 'domain':[['cnn.com', 'usatoday.com'], ['nytimes.com', 'reddit.com'], ['cnn.com'], ['cnn.com'], ['nytimes.com', 'reddit.com'], ['washingtonpost.com', 'nytimes.com'], 'cnn.com', 'cnn.com' ],
                 'same_domain_flag': ['n/a', 'No', 'n/a','yes','n/a','no','n/a', 'n/a']
                 })
```

I've not found a way of referencing the previous record in the dataframe only when the current record of ID and the previous one are the same.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to check if the prior id and domain is the same, the yes, but if the prior id is the same but the prior domain is not then no.

You can achieve this by the following:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                 'flag':['duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'duplicate', 'duplicate', 'non duplicate', 'non-duplicate'],
                 'domain':[['cnn.com', 'usatoday.com'], ['nytimes.com', 'reddit.com'], ['cnn.com'], ['cnn.com'], ['nytimes.com', 'reddit.com'], ['washingtonpost.com', 'nytimes.com'], 'cnn.com', 'cnn.com' ],
                 })

test.loc[test['ID'].eq(test['ID'].shift()) & test['domain'].eq(test['domain'].shift()), 'same_domain_flag'] = 'yes'
test.loc[test['ID'].eq(test['ID'].shift()) & ~test['domain'].eq(test['domain'].shift()), 'same_domain_flag'] = 'no'
```

Output

```
   ID           flag                             domain same_domain_flag
0   1      duplicate            [cnn.com, usatoday.com]              NaN
1   1  non duplicate          [nytimes.com, reddit.com]               no
2   2      duplicate                          [cnn.com]              NaN
3   2  non duplicate                          [cnn.com]              yes
4   3      duplicate          [nytimes.com, reddit.com]              NaN
5   4      duplicate  [washingtonpost.com, nytimes.com]              NaN
6   5  non duplicate                            cnn.com              NaN
7   6  non-duplicate                            cnn.com              NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works. Just to confirm the "~" in the second part of the second eq statement is to indicate that we're looking for cases when the current domain doesn't match the previous one (so effectively saying "not equal to")?

Comment: That is correct